# If we have a function $\alpha (x) = e^{x}$, how would we evaluate the Stieltjes integral $\int_{0}^{t} xd(\alpha^{2})$

Tags: real-analysis

If we have a function $\alpha (x) = e^{x}$, how would we evaluate the Stieltjes integral

$$\int_{0}^{t} xd(\alpha^{2})$$

? I'm not super good at these integrals so I just wanted to see how it could be done in this case. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure if you've been asked to evaluate the above *from the definition* of a Stieltjes integral, or just evaluate it using some known formula or shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha(x)=e^x$, then $\alpha(x)^2=e^{2x}$, and so, using integration by parts, we have that

$$\int_0^t x~\mathrm{d}(\alpha^2)(x)=\biggl[x e^{2x}\biggr]_0^t-\int_0^t e^{2x}~\mathrm{d}x=te^{2t}-\frac{1}{2}(e^{2t}-1).$$

Comment: Please do not answer questions without context. See [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).